# How to find the host name and port number of mysql for Sqoop import and export?

Tags: mysql, centos, sqoop

In case the database name was given, but not the host name and the port number of mysql for Sqoop import or export operations, How to get the unknown details of mysql to proceed ?

Comment: Sqoop is not a magical tool to identify **unknown details of mysql** or anything. You have to tell sqoop all the mysql related configuration.

Comment: Yes, I know that.. I'm not asking using Sqoop, I'm asking for any other way to find the details like using terminal commands or checking config file or some other way.

Comment: Then remove Sqoop import from the question and also sqoop tag..

Comment: I know what is my question. I can't change my question according to your answer.

Comment: why are you feeling offended?

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using clouderaVm then you can use the below command to thind the host name and the port.
For host name,On the linux box then the below command
$hostname

To get the mysql port use the below command in mysql.
mysql>SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='port'